# Where is the struct task_struct definition in the 2.6.30.5 Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the version 2.6.15 kernel, I got that I can rewrite the `task_struct` in the file (include/linux/sched.h)，like:

```
struct task_struct {  
    unsigned did_exec:1;  
    pid_t pid;  
    pid_t tgid;  
    ...
    char hide;
}
```

But, unfortunately, when I upgraded to the version 2.6.30.5, I looked through the same file, I just find a declaration of the `task_struct`, like:

```
struct task_struct;
```

And I have no idea which file I should refer to for the purpose of specifying my own `task_struct`? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `grep` or any other search tool to look for the definition:

```
grep -r '^struct task_struct ' include
```

Or search online at [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/):
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30.5/+search?search=task_struct

The structure is still defined in `include/linux/sched.h`. There's a [forward declaration](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30.5/include/linux/sched.h#L246) which is used in mutually recursive type definitions, and the [definition](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30.5/include/linux/sched.h#L1117) is further down.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Debian squeeze. I see a definition in the headers corresponding to my current kernel, in `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common-vserver/include/linux/sched.h`. The definition starts with

```
struct task_struct {
        volatile long state;    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
        void *stack;
        atomic_t usage;
        unsigned int flags;     /* per process flags, defined below */
        unsigned int ptrace;

        int lock_depth;         /* BKL lock depth */
```

HTH.

Comment: So,am i using a unstable version?but do u have any idea where the defination switch to?any hint?thx

Comment: @kaiwiiho: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: i mean that  whether version 2.6.15 is not stable.And,i think that the defination must exist in a .c file that delcrates the sched.h.But unfortunately,i have not think out a method to find oute c file.And can u give some hints for me?

Comment: @kaiwiiho: Not sure you mean by stable. 2.6.15 is a kernel release. The definition of the struct is in the header file, as far as I can see. What are you looking for?